# What is the quickest way to check 'last login' stored in a table for specific condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have last login data stored for customers  in a mapping table that also includes AD b2c ID. The b2c login is into our web portal .There is a crisis right now because of redundant customers who are not deleted for more than 3 months. So batch process will be run through azure functions to check the table and mark customer entries for deletion- i.e those who haven't logged in for 3 months. I am looking for alternatives to sequentially searching for last logins in the table.

Comment: some structure please

Comment: "sequentially searching" means what exactly? Why is this not simply "select name, max(....) from table group by name having max(...) < <date of 3 months boundary>"?